# Dynamically created task of type Copy is always UP-TO-DATE

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I've prepared a very simple script, that illustrates the problem I see using Gradle 1.7 (need to stick with it because of some plugins not yet supporting newer versions).

I'm trying to dynamically create tasks each of which corresponds to a file in the project directory. This works fine, but the tasks I create never get executed as soon as I assign them type 'Copy'.

Here is my problem `build.gradle`:

```
file('templates').listFiles().each { File f ->

    // THIS LINE DOES NOT WORK
    task "myDist-${f.name}" (type: Copy) {

    // NEXT LINE WORKS
    //task "myDist-${f.name}" {
        doLast {
            println "MYDIST-" + f.name
        }
    }
}

task distAll(dependsOn: tasks.matching { Task task -> task.name.startsWith("myDist")}) {
    println "MYDISTALL"
}

defaultTasks 'distAll'
```

in this way my tasks do not get executed when I call default task calling simply `gradle`:

```
MYDISTALL
:myDist-template1 UP-TO-DATE
:myDist-template2 UP-TO-DATE
:distAll UP-TO-DATE

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

If I remove type `Copy` from my dynamic task (uncommenting the line above), my tasks get executed:

```
MYDISTALL
:myDist-template1
MYDIST-template1
:myDist-template2
MYDIST-template2
:distAll

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

(You'll need to create a folder name `templates` in the same directory where `build.gradle` is located and put couple of empty files into there in order to run the test)

According to the debug output:

> Skipping task ':myDist-template1' as it has no source files.
>
> Skipping task ':myDist-template2' as it has no source files.

So how can I specify source files and make my `Copy` tasks execute?
I've tried adding

```
from( '/absolute/path/to/existing/file' ) {
    into 'myfolder'
}
```

to the task body, I've tried assigning task's `inputs.source file('/my/existing/file')` with no success.
Could you please advise on how to modify my simple script leaving dynamic task creation and keeping my dynamic tasks of type `Copy`?

Thank you!

Edit:
All right, this way the task gets called:

```
file('templates').listFiles().each { File f ->
    task "myDist-${f.name}" (type: Copy) {
        from f
        into 'dist'
        doLast {
            println "MYDIST-" + f.name
        }
    }
}
```

but it looks I must always specify `from`/`into`. It doesn't suffice to do that in the doLast{} body.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A `Copy` task only gets executed if it has something to copy. Telling it what to copy is part of configuring the task, and therefore needs to be done in the *configuration phase*, rather than the *execution phase*. These are very important concepts to understand, and you can read up on them in the [Gradle User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html) or on the [Gradle Forums](http://forums.gradle.org).

`doFirst` and `doLast` blocks get executed in the execution phase, as part of executing the task. Both are too late to tell the task what to copy: `doFirst` gets executed immediately before the main task action (which in this case is the copying), but (shortly) after the `skipped` and `up-to-date` checks (which are based on the task's configuration). `doLast` gets executed after the main task action, and is therefore clearly too late.

Comment: I'm telling the copy task what folder it needs to copy at configuration time (the folder is empty at configuration time). By the time the task gets around to copying the folder at execution time another task has executed and copied the file I need into the source directory. Seems to be working.

Answer (score 2):

I think the following [Gradle User Guide quote](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/working_with_files.html) answers my question the best:

> Secondly, the copy() method can not honor task dependencies when a task is used as a copy source (i.e. as an argument to from()) because it's a method and not a task. As such, if you are using the copy() method as part of a task action, you must explicitly declare all inputs and outputs in order to get the correct behavior.

Comment: That paragraph talks about the `project.copy` method and its drawbacks over the `Copy` task. It isn't related to your problem.

Comment: Well.. it actually is related. Since my real problem was that I was trying to copy in the doLast block of a 'Copy' task (the example I've provided doesn't contain that and is oversimplified) and the task was not triggered because of the missing input sources definition. I moved copying out of the doLast block and 'm happy at the moment :) Thanks for the help!

Comment: Not sure what exactly you mean by "I moved copying out of the doLast block".

Comment: I actually use the [gradle RPM plugin](https://github.com/TrigonicSolutions/gradle-rpm-plugin) (which provides a task of type Copy) and instead of

task "distRpm${templ}" (type: Rpm, dependsOn: xxx) {
   from ...
   into ...

had

task "distRpm${templ}" (type: Rpm, dependsOn: xxx) << {
   from ...
   into ...

(that's what I called 'moved out')

Comment: Your old code was *configuring* the task in a `doLast` action, which, as I've explained, is too late. (This has nothing to do with the `project.copy` method.) Now you are configuring the task in the configuration phase, which is correct.

Comment: The bottom line for me is that a Copy task _must_ have an input sources defined in order to get called (and project.copy method in the doLast won't be called either as is highlighted in the User's Guide example).

Comment: `project.copy` in `doLast` would always be called, but none of the code you showed uses `project.copy`. `project.copy` is an alternative to a `Copy` task, you wouldn't use them together.

Comment: `project.copy` in `doLast` will _not_ be called if the task is of type Copy and has no input sources defined (that's what I've started with).  My bad, didn't see the difference between Copy task and `project.copy` (or why would they treat input sources differently) and didn't include it in my simplified example.

Comment: Right. In that case, no task action whatsoever will be called - the task simply won't be run. Which, I guess, brings us back to my initial answer.

Answer (score 2):

Having read most of the answers to "UP-TO-DATE" Copy tasks in gradle, it appears that the missing part is 'include' keyword:

```
task copy3rdPartyLibs(type: Copy) {
    from 'src/main/jni/libs/'
    into 'src/main/libs/armeabi/'
    include '**/*.so'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Putting `from` and `into` as part of the `doLast` section does not work. An example of a working task definitions is:

```
task copyMyFile(type: Copy) {

    def dockerFile = 'src/main/docker/Dockerfile'
    def copyTo = 'build/docker'

    from dockerFile
    into copyTo

    doLast {
        println "Copied Docker file [$dockerFile] to [$copyTo]"
    }
}
```

Not the behavior I was expecting.
Using gradle 3.2.1

Comment: Did you mean `def dockerFile = 'src/main/docker/Dockerfile'` ?