# Zip task marked as up-to-date

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

Hi I try to collect plugins from sub-folder, zip them and copy to my export folder.

```
task buildPlugin {
  dependsOn ':empty-plugin:build'
}

task exportPlugin(type: Zip) {
  dependsOn buildPlugin

  // create new export folder as destination for nightly build
  def folder = '/export';
  def file = "${project.name}-sdk-${project.version}";

  // collect all plugins into cwc-sdk zip file
  baseName = file
  fileTree("cwc-plugin").each({
    if (it.name.endsWith(".zip")) {
        from it.absolutePath
    }
  })

  // move cwc-sdk zip file into export destination folder
  copy { into folder from file }
  delete file
}
```

I run clean task first. The gradle logs:

```
:api:compileJava
:api:processResources
:api:classes
:api:jar
:empty-plugin:compileJava
:empty-plugin:processResources
:empty-plugin:classes
:empty-plugin:jar
:empty-plugin:assemble
:empty-plugin:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:empty-plugin:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:empty-plugin:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:empty-plugin:test UP-TO-DATE
:empty-plugin:check UP-TO-DATE
:api:javadoc
:empty-plugin:zip
:empty-plugin:build
:buildPlugin
:exportPlugin UP-TO-DATE

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 2.097 secs
```

While first run :exportPlugin is marked as UP-TO-DATE and I don't get the zipped file from build. When I run :exportPlugin again everything is fine. It's also fine when I chain both tasks manually (rungradle clean, next run gradle buildPlugin, run gradle exportPlugin by doublclick to tasks at IDEA)

I think the order of tasks are still ok. I don't need to work with `mustRunAfter`.

I also played around with `copySpec`, `buildplugin.outputs.files`. But nothing helps.

Can anybody help me to solve this issue for initial build run?
Thanks!

**Update**:
A Zip task is an abstracted Copy task

> AbstractCopyTask is the base class for all copy tasks. ([Docu](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Zip.html))

I found this [comment from Peter Niederwieser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20254032/2199721)

> A Copy task only gets executed if it has something to copy. Telling it what to copy is part of configuring the task, and therefore needs to be done in the configuration phase, rather than the execution phase.

How do I change `from it.absolutePath` code line inside fileTree loop to be part during configuration phase?