# Task of Type Copy not executed

Tags: gradle

I am facing an issue executing my task of type `Copy`,:

> Skipping the task as it has no source files

I get if I run in the debug mode.

My `Plugin.groovy` class (where the call to the plugin task in made )

```
Task task = project.tasks.create("makeJarPlugin", MakeJarPluginTask.class)
task.dependsOn("clearDistPlugin", "build")
```

My `MakeJarPluginTask.grrovy`

```
class MakeJarPluginTask extends Copy {
   @TaskAction
   def makeJar(){
      logger.lifecycle("creating a jar *********************")
      delete('dist/')
      from('build/intermediates/bundles/release')
      into('dist/')
      include('classes.jar')
      def jarName = new VersionName().getNameWithVersion() + '.jar'
      rename('classes.jar', jarName)
   }
}
```

Now, I execute this task in my android studio project using

```
gradlew makeJarPlugin --info
```

It gives me the output:

```
Skipping task ':network:makeJar1' as it has no source files.
makeJar1 UP-TO-DATE
```

There is something wrong with the type `Copy` as in the same way I execute my delete task and it executes. Any pointers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20254032/542270) answer may be helpful.

Hint: you need to configure the task. Otherwise it won't be executed since the whole configuration is done in `makeJar` which is too late since this is an action.

Instead of using copy you can also try:

```
class MakeJarPluginTask extends DefaultTask {
   @TaskAction
   def makeJar() {
     logger.lifecycle("creating a jar *********************")
      delete('dist/')
      project.copy {    

         from('build/intermediates/bundles/release')
         into('dist/')
         include('classes.jar')
         def jarName = new VersionName().getNameWithVersion() + '.jar'
         rename('classes.jar', jarName)
      }
   }
}
```