# Gradle copy task not finding source files when leftShift (<<) operator used

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradlew

I have the following gradle task in a subproject's **build.gradle** file to copy **file.txt** from a directory called **from_dir/** to a directory **to_dir/** and rename it to **fileRenamed.txt**:

```
task copyRenameFile(type: Copy) {
    System.out.println("copyRenameFile begin")
    from('from_dir')
    into('to_dir')
    include('file.txt')
    rename('file.txt', 'fileRenamed.txt')
    System.out.println("copyRenameFile end")
}

build.finalizedBy(copyRenameFile)
```

When I run `gradlew :subprojectname:build`, this task performs the copy as expected after the build task is finalized, but it executes the `println`s during the configuration phase, before the build task.

In an attempt to make the `println`s appear after the build phase when the copy is actually being executed, I tried using the `<<` operator like so:

```
task copyRenameFile(type: Copy) << {
```

But this results in the task beings skipped with the following message:

```
[INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter] Skipping task ':subprojectname:copyRenameFile' as it has no source files.
```

Does this mean **file.txt** could not be found during the execution phase?  Why?

**EDIT**: After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20254032/1245897) answer, I now understand that my usage of the `<<` operator is causing the configuration phase to skip this task and this is the reason the source files are not found.  So I guess I can't use the `<<` operator, but how else can I make the `println`s occur when the task is being executed and not when it is being configured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
task copyRenameFile(type: Copy) {
    doFirst{
        System.out.println("copyRenameFile begin")
    }

    from('from_dir')
    into('to_dir')
    include('file.txt')
    rename('file.txt', 'fileRenamed.txt')

    doLast{
        System.out.println("copyRenameFile end")
    }
}

build.finalizedBy(copyRenameFile)
```

I got rid of the `<<` and instead used `doFirst` and `doLast` to ensure my `println`s occured during the execution phase.